# Longevity of electronic pianos

Tags: piano, maintenance

It seems to me that an acoustic piano is something that (with suitable care and maintenance) should last for generations. If anything breaks, it can be repaired.

With electronic pianos, I can anticipate situations where some component goes out of production and a broken piano can't be repaired.

Specifically I am asking about the kind of electronic piano that aims to be a substitute for an acoustic piano, and is built like a piece of furniture.

- How long do manufacturers typically support electronic pianos (by producing spare parts etc.)
- How long beyond that period could one realistically expect to keep using an electronic piano?
- How much of the mechanical workings could be expected to be repairable in a hypothetical future where the manufacturer is not making parts?

(The inspiration for this is that I'm wondering whether a piano is a suitable wedding present -- something one would be reluctant to part with or upgrade).

Comment: i heard somewhere that acoustic pianos actually deteriorate over time under the strain of their string tension, and eventually cannot be properly tuned any more. That being said, I did one time play on a square grand that was allegedly about 100 years old, and it was playable though not pitched at A 440.

Comment: I bought a Korg C5000 from new in the late 1980's and I still play it most days. Electronically I've had no issues with it at all - all the switches and sliders and sockets still work just fine. About five years ago I had a keyboard tech replace the rubber membrane used for the velocity sensing switches in the keyboard as it was sounding as though I was hitting each key at ff. So Korg spares for old pianos are still around even on their pianos that have been out of production for years. Don't know if my experience is typical, but I think I've had my money's worth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably safe to assume that digital piano will be supported for the duration of the warranty. Then some [Rolland](http://www.rolandus.com/support/service_repair) and [Yamaha](http://usa.yamaha.com/support/warranty/pianos/) models feature up to five year warranty (in comparison, Yamaha acoustic pianos have ten year warranty). I think this should be enough as for the wedding present; many wedding presents are household items that, when normally used, do not last for ages.

From [this blog](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=594750) seems that electronics can work for tens of years if little used, or used carefully. There are many items from 1980s or about still in use. However if something breaks, I think, this will be the end of the instrument.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Yamaha ps55, a Yamaha psr 330 and a Yamaha dgx 202, I bought all 3 keyboards used well over 15 years ago and I've had zero problems out of any of them, if you take care of your instruments, then your instruments will take care of you

Comment: sure, but his point was about component failure,not lack of external care. Striking the keys carefully and so preserving the rubber membrane, and wiping the dust off the casing does not make the circuitry inside last any longer.

Comment: The precautions that you mentioned do help maintain the circuitry inside soooooo yea......

Comment: how exactly does wiping dust off the external casing protect the components on the circuit boards ?

Comment: I clean the internal as well as the external, and I have keyboard covers